# Different output in Lua and LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, lua

I'm using TeX Live 2020 (with LuaLaTeX 1.12.0) and Lua 5.3.

---

When I compile the following `.tex` file using `lualatex --shell-escape` the content of the resulting `.pdf` is `a`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
T = 
{
    { "a", 5 },
    { "b", 2 }
}    
\end{luacode}

\begin{document}
\luaexec{tex.print(T[1])}
\end{document}
```

Further, `T[1]=="a"` and `T[2]==5`, `T[3]` does not output a value and does not throw an error in LuaLaTeX. `T[1][1]` and `T[1][2]` also do not do anything, but `T[2][1]` throws

> `attempt to index a number value (field '?')`

---

Running similar code directly in Lua, namely this code:

```lua
T = 
{
    { "a", 5 },
    { "b", 2 }
}

print(T[1])
```

I get the expected output, namely the adress of the table:

> `table: 0x559417e736b0`

---

What is happening here, and what am I doing wrong?
I am very confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a 'feature' of `luacode`: if I either run everything into one line or use `\directlua` then all is well. Specifically, if you trace the TeX, the outer set of braces are being lost so Lua is seeing

```lua
T =

    { "a", 5 },
    { "b", 2 }
```

which gives the result you see.

That suggests a bug in `luacode` where a brace group is dropped, probably a delimited argument. In general, I'd avoid `luacode` and either use `\directlua` with 'safe' Lua snippets or put them in a separate file and use `require()`. (The Lua file could be part of the TeX source using `filecontents.)

Comment: Thank you, you're right! Should have read the documentation. It is indeed a feature of the `luacode` environment, but there is `luacode*` which makes the original code work.